# replace the first or nth line of file with ruby

Tags: ruby, file

How would I replace the first line of a text file or xml file using ruby? I'm having problems replicating a strange xml API and need to edit the document instruction after I create the XML file. It is strange that I have to do this, but in this case it is necessary.

Comment: Please post the code the does not work so that we can see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you trying to modifying the file on disk, or read the contents and then modify a particular line before using it?

Comment: @Phrogz whichever way is most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you are editing XML, use a tool specially designed for the task. `sub`, `gsub` and regex are not good choices if the XML being manipulated is not under your control.

Use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to parse the XML, locate nodes and change them, then emit the updated XML.

There are many examples on SO showing how to do this, plus the tutorials on the Nokogiri site.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways you can do this:

1. Use `ARGF` (assuming that your ruby program takes a file name as a command line parameter)

   ```
   ruby -e "puts ARGF.to_a[n]" yourfile.xml
   ```
2. Open the file regularly then read `n` lines

   ```
   File.open("yourfile") { |f|
     line = nil
     n.times { line = f.gets }
     puts line
   }
   ```

   This approach is less intensive on memory, as only a single line is considered at a time, it is also the simplest method.
3. Use `IO.readlines()` (will only work if the entire file will fit in memory!)

   ```
   IO.readlines("yourfile")[n]
   ```

   `IO.readlines(...)` will read every line from your file into an array.

Where `n` in all the above examples is the `nth` line of your file.